# Webpack 5 ModuleFederationPlugin - Load JS-File during runtime

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have an React-application (Micro-Frontend) which is exported using Webpack5 and ModuleFederationPlugin. This app loads some variables from a JS-File during runtime (e.g. the URL of the Backend).

Is there a chance to replace the JS-File during runtime, so that I can inject some other values for the variables in the JS-File?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i can follow but you have an application a (react-app) and b (JS-File server) ?

If so, just rebuild your application b with same settings. The next time application a requests the sources of application b your new file is loaded